# how to create table in sqlite database android?

Tags: android

i have a class by name "Buys", it have some variables such as price ,wight ,name and...
i create a table from its class but when i want to insert to that,error occur.
error said "table buys have no column named weigh".
here is my code .please help.
thanks

```
public class Buys {

    int id;
    String fname;
    String lname;
    String product;
    double weigh;
    double price;
    double total_price;
    String date;
}


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Logcat tag
    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WorkerManeger";

    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_WORKERS = "workers";
    private static final String TABLE_BUYS = "Buys";
    private static final String TABLE_PAYMENT_WORKERS = "payment_workers";
    private static final String TABLE_OTHER_PAYMENT = "Otehr_payment";

    private static final String KEY_W_NAME = "fname";
    private static final String KEY_W_FAMILY = "lname";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String KEY_WEIGH= "weigh";
    private static final String KEY_PRICE= "price";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL_PRICE = "total_price";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUYS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_BUYS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_W_NAME
        + " TEXT," + KEY_W_FAMILY + " TEXT," + KEY_PRODUCT
        + " TEXT," + KEY_WEIGH + " REAL," + KEY_PRICE + " REAL," + KEY_TOTAL_PRICE + " REAL," + KEY_DATE + "DATETIME" + ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUYS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_BUYS);
    // create new tables
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: You need to list the error. If you're trying to expand on a database that is already in your memory, you need to upgrade the version of your db so that it will call onUpgrade.

Answer (score 3):

While creating your table, you miss a space here:

```
KEY_DATE + "DATETIME" + ")";
```

It has to be

```
KEY_DATE + " DATETIME" + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this command :

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUYS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_BUYS + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_W_NAME
        + " TEXT, " + KEY_W_FAMILY + " TEXT, " + KEY_PRODUCT
        + " TEXT, " + KEY_WEIGH + " REAL, " + KEY_PRICE + " REAL, " + KEY_TOTAL_PRICE + " REAL," + KEY_DATE + " DATETIME" + " )";
```